# Blender 3.1 lights burned-out on Ubuntu

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, lighting, linux

I'm having a nice looking scene in Material preview (Blender v3.1.2).
So far looking good with the default HDRI (I'm not sure exactly how this works).

[image]

[image]

I then added a simple `Sun` light, checked `Lighting > Scene Lights` and now my whole thing is burned in both `Material Preview` and `Rendered (Eevee)` while totally black with `Rendered (Cycles)`.

[image]

[image]

My textures are nothing special, BSDF + changed Base Color to green, blue etc...

[image]

I'm working with unitless values (`Scene > Units > Unit System > None`) so I thought it may be that (never had any issue before tho) but no success.
Of course, turning down the strength of either a `Sun` or an `Area` light does nothing.

Here is how it looks with a 30W area light, it's burned to crystal clear white.

[image]

---

Here are my `Scene > World` settings, nothing special neither

[image]

Nothing funky in the Color Management neither.

### [image]

So, either I do have a `convert 0.001 strength` to `500k WATTS` mode or I'm missing a setting somewhere.
Forgot to mention by my previous render went perfectly well (no burning like that).

---

Update: I just tried to render it, to see how bad it would look and it's actually perfect while rendering for some reason...meanwhile I cannot really spend my time rendering to see the actual result.
A real solution would be highly likable.

[image]

Here's my outliner, everything is shown in the same way (`viewports` or `renders`).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: relaunch Blender if getting out of Ubuntu's suspend mode.

---

While writing this question, Stackexchange recommended me to look at those 2 other questions so I gave them a read.

[image]

I finished on this [Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/8i73yz/comment/dyqq7s4/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), where the author talks about the real render in real life and how it looks.
This gave me the idea to try to render it out. It failed and I noticed a `CUDA error` on the bottom middle of the UI.

Double checked my GPU settings, everything was totally fine and nothing moved.

I gave Blender a reboot and everything is **working fine now**.
The culprit? Ubuntu and the way it handles the suspend mode, not the first time I do have an issue when getting out of it. Time to move to Arch I guess...